# Can I expose multiple Kubernetes services on the same external IP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, azure-aks

I have several image do different thing. Now, I expose them like these commands:

```
kubectl create deployment work_deployment_1 --image=username/work_image_1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
kubectl expose deployment work_deployment_1 --type=LoadBalancer --port=8000
```

and then

```
kubectl create deployment work_deployment_2 --image=username/work_image_2:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
kubectl expose deployment work_deployment_2 --type=LoadBalancer --port=9000
```

After deployment creating and exposing, I check them by `kubectl get service`, the result of it will like:

```
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
work_deployment_1      LoadBalancer   10.245.197.226   159.65.210.104   8000:30798/TCP   30m
work_deployment_2      LoadBalancer   10.245.168.156   159.65.129.201   9000:32105/TCP   51s
```

Can I make deployment (or deployments), expose `same_external-ip:8000` and `same_external-ip:9000`, instead of address above (`159.65.210.104:8000` and `159.65.129.201:9000`) ?

Comment: If both services are HTTP, are you looking for an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) instead?  That would let you serve them on different HTTP paths on the same host and port.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have an Ingress controller installed in your cluster to handle incoming traffic and route it to the appropriate service. Examples of Ingress controllers include Nginx Ingress, Traefik, and Istio.

Another way around that we use in Azure and Google Cloud is that we Expose the services via App Gateway in Azure & HTTPS Global LB

In GCP case and the services are exposed on the LB single Anycast IP.

In GCP Case workflow is:
*Create a Kubernetes service> Create a backend service that references each Kubernetes service > Create a URL map that maps the incoming requests to the appropriate backend service based on the requested URL or hostname > Create a target HTTP proxy that references the URL map > Create a Google Cloud HTTPS load balancer and configure it to use the target HTTP proxy*

Each time the Front End will be using the SAME Anycast IP & Different ports in front end...

In your private cloud case I will refer using Traefik you can follow their documentation on this:https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/kubernetes-ingress/